# ¿Porque mi doropdown no funciona cuando agrego el datatables de boostrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Actualmente estoy utilizando el datatables de boostrap junto con un dropdown que descargue que tambien es de boostrap.

Si no agrego el datatbles funciona correctamente mi menu, pero si agrego toda la estructura de mi datatable deja de funcionar.

Linkeos que agrego:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Codigo de la tabla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>




<style>
td
{
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <br />

   <div class="container">
   <table id="example"></table>
   </div>                             





<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": [
   ["PHP Data Object | PDO","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PDO"],
   ["Object Oriented PHP","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PHP OOP"],
   ["jQuery Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/jQuery"],
   ["Ajax Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/Ajax"],
   ["CRUD Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/CRUD"],
   ["Pagination Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/Pagination"],
   ["PHP MySQLi Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/MySQLi"],
   ["HTML5 Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/HTML5"],
   ["Pagination Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/Pagination"],
   ["PHP MySQLi Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/MySQLi"],
   ["HTML5 Tutorials","http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/HTML5"]
   ],
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Article Title" },
            { "title": "Tutorial Link" }
        ]
    } );   
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#example')
 .addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Codigo del dropdown:

```
<nav id="contenedorEncabezado" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SoftTicket</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="buscador" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Qué estás buscando?">
        </div>
        <button id="botonBuscar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Opciones <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Cambiar idioma (inglés)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#animatedModal02" id="imagen_promotor" onclick="indexonP();">Se un promotor</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Iniciar sesión</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                     <div class="row">
                     <?php
                      //llamar funcion estatica de la clase auth
                     Auth::getUserAuth();?>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Inicia sesión con:
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="?login=Facebook" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="?login=Google" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Google</a>
                                </div>
                                Ingresa tus datos:
                                 <form action="login/validar.php" method="post" class="form"  role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                        <div for="caja1" class="form-group">
                                             <label for="caja1" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
                                             <input type="text" id="caja1" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div for="caja2" class="form-group">
                                             <label for="caja2" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                                             <input type="password" id="caja2" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <input type="submit" name="prueba"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">  
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> Mantente conectado
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                ¿Eres nuevo aquí? <a href="#animatedModal06" id="registro" onclick="indexonPro();"><b>Únete con nosotros</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tuve que agregar esta linea de codigo al final de mi `document.ready`

```
$('body .dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```